# C++ Error when mixing template class and template method

Tags: c++, class, templates, header

I have a class that takes a size type as a parameter in case one doesn't want to use size_t or another hard coded type which would require casting and checking for overflows.
This class also has some methods taking a second template type :

```
template< typename SizeType = uint32_t >
class BufferReader
{
    SizeType m_nPosition;

    template< typename T >
    T Read();
}
```

My problem is, what is the syntax to implement this ?

```
template< typename SizeType, typename T >
T BufferReader< SizeType >::Read()
{
    // ...
}
```

Which gives me an error :

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'class core::BufferReader<SizeType>'
```

Or :

```
template< typename T >
template< typename SizeType >
T BufferReader< SizeType >::Read()
{
    // ...
}
```

Which gives the same error.

Or anything else ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example is nearly right, you just need to have the template parameters of the class first and those of the function second:

```
template< typename SizeType >
template< typename T >
T BufferReader< SizeType >::Read()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it.  You have to stack the `template`s as in the declaration: first the class and then the member.

```
template < typename SizeT >
template < typename T >
T
BufferReader<SizeT>::Read()
{
  return T {};
}
```

Note that the code can be simplified by defining the function right in the class body but I understand that some people will prefer to separate declaration from definition for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not just aesthetics. There's a convenience and maintenance argument, even though your implementations aren't going to move very far.